# Отключить модерацию комментариев у роли в WP

Tags: wordpress

В настройках wordpress выставил, что комментарий появляется, если автор уже имеет ранее одобренные комментарии. 
Но я добавил новую привилегированную роль пользователей, находясь в которой комментарий не должен отсылаться на модерацию, а сразу же публиковаться в любом случае. Кто знает, как это сделать? Нужно чтобы комментарии данных привилегированных пользователей не отправлялись на модерацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед присвоением статуса комментарию, он фильтруется. Попробуйте добавить такой код в файл функций темы:

```
function pre_comment_approved_filter( $approved, $commentdata ) {
    // Определите роль пользователя и измените значение $approved на 1,
    // если ему можно публиковать комментарии без одобрения.
    // if () {
    //   $approved = 1;
    // }
    return $approved;
}

add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'pre_comment_approved_filter', 10, 2 );
```